# Template in C++ and my initial understanding to that

Tags: c++

```
class X {}; 

template <typename T>   
struct Test
{
   typedef T value;   
};


template <>
struct Test<X>    
{
   static int value;
};

int Test<X>::value = 0;


template <typename T>

void f( T const & )
{
   Test<T>::value; // during first pass, Test<T>::value is interpreted as a value

}
int main()
{

  X x; f( x ); 
}
```

I try to understand the above template code for C++. 
on the Main I declared x of class X and calling the function f with x as argument.

From the template f it expects a reference of constant type T  so it become `Test<x>::value;`
then it looks into structure `Test<X>` and it's member value.

My questions are:

1. Why need to declared both structure of `Test` and `Test<X>`?
2. `Test<T>::value` basically means getting the value member of the Test structure.is this the normal generic way to access a structure. Seems a bit confusing.
3. class X is a place holder? there's nothing inside

Answer (score 0):

1. It's called template specialization. You are saying that `Test<X>` is a special case and is different than other `Test<T>`
2. You're either accessing the static `value` (for cases where `T` is `struct X`) or referencing the type `value` (for all other cases of `T`)
3. It's a tag. A class whose mere name/type is triggering behavior. Make a `struct Y{};` and try using that. It ought to have a compiler error accessing `Test<Y>::value`. As for why f is set up the way it is, I do not know. I would have assumed it should be called F(); and no instance passed, but I have no clue what you're trying to accomplish with this.

This code is using concepts that generally fall under "metaprogramming." You might have more luck using that as a keyword.